# Are Xbox achievement names unique?

Tags: achievements, xbox-network

Ok, so I'm a mediocre 20K+ Gamerscore player, but I've always been interested by the names of the achievements.

My special favourite is Saboteur's "Pint and a Shag" cheevo.

In my years of playing, I've never noticed the same achievement name used for different games.

Are there any known regulations restricting developers choice of names?

Answer (score 1):

There are in fact a lot of achievements with the same names. Kotaku once made an [article](http://kotaku.com/5428866/the-most-common-achievement-and-trophy-names) about the most common ones like Untouchable, Hero, Survivor to name a few.

I believe the only regulation that exists has to do with the amount of achievements allowed for one game. There are no known regulations for achievement names. Though you can assume that offensive ones probably aren't allowed.